# Customizing page content layout

Tags: themes, pages, customization

For a while now I have been building WordPress based sites for clients.  These sites tend to be brochure sites so feature a collection of pages all with slightly different layouts within an overarching main layout and style.

Upto this point I have either created Pages in the WordPress admin panel and then created a page template with the content embedded into it (not great when the client want to be able to update the page) or created a new page and a generic "page" template and then placed content into this using HTML in the editor (not great for the user trying to edit the content in the editor, or when the editor decides to add more HTML tags)

Is there another way to easily create pages where the user can easily update the content using the editor but wont risk screwing up the layout?  something like multiple editors or content areas in the admin panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with this plugin nor its author, it's just a plugin I've found to be indispensable in my Wordpress tool kit. So this is not an advertisement for a plugin.

The plugin you want is: [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). It's a free plugin that'll make your life a lot easier for varied post editing pages and whatnot.

Comment: You don't really explain *how* the plugin can be used to solve the OP's question.

Comment: Obviously the Stewarty thought otherwise which is why he marked my answer as correct. If Stewarty didn't feel as though I answered his question, I would have clarified. And I think I did answer his question, he wanted a way to create pages where he can add additional fields for the user to enter content, ACF does that. Going to the ACF site presents with with code examples and use cases, there is no point repeating what the site I linked already has...